# ROS on Odroid U3

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ros-hydro, armhf, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set up my [Odroid U3](http://hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php) with ROS. Here's a list of problems and their potential solutions, but I don't have a ton of experience with this and I was hoping to tap greater minds:

- **Problem**: ROS is built for x86 architectures, not ARM architectures.
- **Solution**: Use the [UbuntuARM](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM) installation
- **Issue**: This ties us down to Hydro. ROS also has weak (but getting better!) support for ARM, which is still an issue for many packages.
- **Problem**: Odroid's preconfigured Linux install is Saucy Salamander, 13.10, which is supported by Indigo.
- **Solution**: Install Ubuntu 13.04 on the Odroid and use the UbuntuARM installation with Hydro.
- **Issue**: I have to install an unsupported and old OS on the Odroid U3, preventing me from using any developments from Indigo as well.

Anything else I'm missing? Have many others installed ROS on Odroid or on ARM architectures (Beagleboard, Raspberry Pi, etc.)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187472/ros-on-odroid-u3/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you've stated most of the current issues exactly.

I now have experimental binary builds of Indigo available for Trusty armhf: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An official image of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty has been released for all ODROID boards
http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=5234
http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=4823

You could install ROS Indigo from source with Ubuntu 14.04 and get the prerequisites from the UbuntuARM debian repository. It looks like the generic tools may be available for 'all' distributions, otherwise you may have to install those from source too.

I used Ubuntu 13.04 Raring with ROS Hydro from the UbuntuARM debian repo a year ago on my ODROID U3 board, but I have not used UbuntuARM  recently.

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-08-08**:
I'd tried ROS Indigo before, and it was getting pretty messy. Trying a 13.04 image from Odroid, and I'm hoping that works better!